# VSCode Code Runner not following settings.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I set my settings.json to Anaconda python 3.6.10 but Code runner still runs the code in 3.7.6. I used OS to check and in fact, that is true. I then used terminal to run my file and it is Python 3.6.10. How can I change my Code Runner to run at whatever version I set in the .vscode settings.json file?

Answer (score 1):

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName",
},
```

With this it should follow the anaconda settings in VS Code.